# Windows Installation Error: The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program windows

Tags: installation, gazebo-11, windows, cmake

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to install Gazebo on my Windows 10 machine and I'm following the official tutorial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_on_windows&cat=install). When I try to configure and build the dependencies I get the following error:

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

It's clear that it's caused by CMake, but I couldn't find out the problem
Any idea on how to fix it?
Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26845/windows-installation-error:-the-c-compiler-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program-windows/) by [Abdo_Ameen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46386/abdo_ameen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Not sure if the real problems is the use of `x86_x64`instead of `x86_amd64`, is the only thing that catch my attention from that log.

As an alternative, I would recommend exploring the new options of installing Gazebo driven by different community members and detailed here https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2901. Particularly the conda-forge installation is [most active one](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2899).

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2021-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdo_Ameen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46386/abdo_ameen/) on 2021-04-21**:
I followed the conda-forge installation and I executed the two commands successfully, but there are no instructions on how to run Gazebo after installation, simply typing "gazebo" on the cmd terminal does not run it

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-04-21**:
You probably need to call it from the "Anaconda prompt" see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/getting-started/

**Comment by [Abdo_Ameen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46386/abdo_ameen/) on 2021-04-21**:
it does not run using Anaconda prompt neither ("gazebo" is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.)

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-04-21**:
Was the problem fixed in https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2976#event-4625876038?

**Comment by [Abdo_Ameen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/46386/abdo_ameen/) on 2021-04-22**:
yes, in another way, simply by installing ROS, and I got Gazebo included by default.
Thank you for your help Mr. Rivero